# Unable to get Firepad to work properly

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, codemirror, firepad

I created a Firebase (https://mkaminsky.firebaseio.com/), and am attempting to use Firepad to create a code collaboration tool. I created this html file, as said in the example(https://github.com/firebase/firepad/blob/master/examples/code.html).

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- See http://www.firepad.io/docs/ for detailed embedding docs. -->
   <html>
      <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8" />
         <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js"></script>

         <script src="codemirror/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
         <script src="codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript.js"></script>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="codemirror/lib/codemirror.css" />

         <script src="firepad.js"></script>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="firepad.css" />
         <style>
             html { height: 100%; }
             body { margin: 0; height: 100%; position: relative; }
             .firepad {
              position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; height: auto;
              }
         </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <button type="button">Test</button> 
      <div id="firepad-container"></div>

      <script>
         //// Initialize Firebase.
         var firepadRef = new Firebase('https://mkaminsky.firebaseio.com/');

         //// Create CodeMirror (with line numbers and the JavaScript mode).
         var codeMirror = CodeMirror(document.getElementById('firepad-container'), {
           lineNumbers: true,
           mode: 'javascript'
         });

         //// Create Firepad.
         var firepad = Firepad.fromCodeMirror(firepadRef, codeMirror);

         //// Initialize contents.
         firepad.on('ready', function() {
           if (firepad.isHistoryEmpty()) {
            firepad.setText('//hello');
           }
         });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, this code does not work as it should. It displays the code editor, complete with syntax highlighting, but does not execute the "setText('//hello');" method. Any other commands put in its place also do not work.

In addition, the button is not displayed in the html page.

I have tested and verified that the Firebase works properly.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code and opened it in Chrome, and it worked correctly ("//hello" showed up in the editor).

Are you getting any errors in the console?  What browser are you using?

Comment: there are two errors:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'LIST_TYPE' of undefined firepad.js:12
Uncaught ReferenceError: Firepad is not defined index.html:47

Comment: I got it to work. It turns out that I was using the wrong firepad.js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be the isHistoryEmpty() code doesn't run for you simply because it worked **once** and now the history is not empty?

```
$ curl  https://mkaminsky.firebaseio.com/.json 
{"users":{"-J6J90xrR-D-XC6WE23F":{"color":"#d5b3ff"}},"history":{"A0":{"a":"-J6HUBET5icmC-yXAkJb","o":["//hello"]}}}
```

Try clearing your firebase or using a fresh namespace for the firepad documents.  The easiest way to test fresh namespaces is

```
Firepad.fromCodeMirror(firepadRef.push(), codeMirror);
```

which consistently runs the isHistoryEmpty() branch for me (tested on https://cben-sandbox.firebaseio.com/, Chrome & Firefox).

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely missing CSS formatting. As per the [documentation](https://firepad.io/docs/#getting_started_with_codemirror), add the following CSS rule:

```css
.firepad {
    width: 700px;
    height: 450px;
    background-color: #f62; /* dark orange background */
}
```

**Before CSS Styling**

[image: Before CSS Styling]

**After CSS Styling**

[image: After CSS Styling]